# PHP and .htaccess redirect woodoo

Tags: .htaccess

I'm a little stuck with with my .htaccess redirect.
It was working find while I was with PHP4 but the recent move to a new host with PHP5 have changed things for which I've no clue.

I'm working on a URL shortening service. Here, for a URL like `http://example.com/e72b0f`, it gives me `http://example.com/forward.php?e72b0f`

Earlier with my .htaccess file, the "forward.php?" was masked (hidden). How can I bring back this behavior. Here is the .htaccess for your reference.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9a-z]{6})$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*) http://example.com/forward.php?%1 [L]
```

Btw, I also do not rule out the issue being in the PHP Script. The developer that did it for me is too busy to look at it.

Comment: check if apache mod-rewrite is install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rewrite to an `http://` URL that the server doesn't think is in the site, `mod_rewrite` will do a redirect instead of just a rewrite.  In order to see if this is happening, make a page that has nothing in it but

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>
```

and see if says it's going to "nsfw.in".

Either way, you should be able to strip off the `http:// nsfw.in` from the beginning of the URL and just rewrite it to `/forward.php?%1`.  You may need to add a PT flag in order for it to be interpreted as a URL and not a FS path.

Comment: Super! That's it, I just removed the actual URL and ask it to redirect from the root and it worked. Thanks a lot.